# How to connect to the remote MS SQL Server database via Jetbrains DataGrip?

Tags: sql-server, database, datagrip

I am using the latest version of DataGrip and wonder if it is possible to connect to the remote SQL Server by providing IP address.

Comment: There is a tutorial BTW https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2016/06/21/connecting-datagrip-to-ms-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

Sure that is possible.

> Open `File -> Data Sources` or press `CMD-;`
>
> Press `+ -> Data Source -> SQL Server`

Input:

```
Host: <IP-address or hostname>
Database: <database-name>
User: 
Password:
```

> Make sure you have the Driver and press `Test Connection`

Comment: what about ports, firewall settings, mixed mode authentication, all these are important to setup as pre-requisites before even trying to test a connection with datagrip

Comment: @TheJackal - good point, what about you go ahead and improve the answer with anything else you deem appropriate to simply set a new MS SQL connection :)

Comment: Default port on my remote server (1433) was changed. Another problem was driver absence. That's why i couldn't connect. I fixed everything and now can connect. Thanks for the answer.